# jquery modernizr application cache

Tags: jquery

I noticed that IE 9 does not support application cache. How can I use the modernizr in Jquery so it is supported?

Comment: modernizr does not extend a browser functionality, it detects what features are supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modernizer lists "polyfils" which can be used to plug gaps in browsers.

[HTML5 Cross-browser Polyfills on modernizer wiki](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills)

If you scroll to about the middle there is one listed for application cache.

Comment: n.b. good point from @undefined (+1 from me), modernizer is for feature detection not adding features, but their wiki is a handy resource for polyfills.